# I need to print my array like a table

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print a two dimensional array with string values like a table.

So far my code is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Employee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wages[][] =
            {
                {"Emp", "Hours", "Wages"},
                {"Bobby", "45", "35"},
                {"Rick", "15",  "33"},
                {"Mike", "66", "50"},
                {"Jayme", "15", "45"}
         };         

       System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(wages));
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[[Emp, Hours, Wages], [Bobby, 45, 35], [Rick, 15, 33], [Mike, 66, 50], [Jayme, 15, 45]]
```

I need it to look more like a table with separate rows (5 rows 3 columns)

Comment: Then you need to iterate the array manually and print just what you need when you need it.

Comment: You can warp those in an object You can implement the method toString to format your output

Comment: There appear to be [some good answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782080/java-printing-two-dimensional-array) available.

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate in your array and print all entries like this.

```
String wages[][] = {
    {"Emp", "Hours", "Wages"},
    {"Bobby", "45", "35"},
    {"Rick", "15",  "33"},
    {"Mike", "66", "50"},
    {"Jayme", "15", "45"}
};

Arrays.stream(wages).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output

```
[Emp, Hours, Wages]
[Bobby, 45, 35]
[Rick, 15, 33]
[Mike, 66, 50]
[Jayme, 15, 45]
```

[Try it online !](https://ideone.com/HmyqOU)

Comment: I get an error:                                                                                             
    /tmp/java_naSVVl/Employee.java:15: error: ';' expected
     Arrays.stream(wages).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);tring(wages));              
                                                                                         ^
1 error

Comment: Which version of java do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wages.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < wages[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(wages[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If the length of the strings cause a problem in displaying, then you could do something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Employee {

    public int[] getMaxLength(String wages[][]) {
        int lengths[] = new int[wages[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lengths.length; i++) lengths[i] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < wages.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wages[i].length; j++) {
                if (wages[i][j].length() > lengths[j]) lengths[j] = wages[i][j].length();
            }
        }
        return lengths;
    }

    public static String friendlyString(String input, int size) {
        while (input.length() < size) input += " ";
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wages[][] =
            {
                {"Emp", "Hours", "Wages"},
                {"Bobby", "45", "35"},
                {"Rick", "15",  "33"},
                {"Mike", "66", "50"},
                {"Jayme", "15", "45"}
         };         

        int sizes[] = getMaxLength(wages);
        for (int i = 0; i < wages.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wages[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(friendlyString(wages[i][j], sizes[j]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly for me, thank you.

Comment: @RyanAsciutto you are welcome. If the solution solved your problem, you might consider accepting this answer as the correct one by clicking on the check mark to the left of it, so future users might be helped by it as well.